# Swift - Network Requests and Background Queue

Tags: swift, api, networking, grand-central-dispatch

just wanted some clarification on the best practices to make network api calls in Swift 2.

Here is how my typical network requests looks like to download JSON data:

```
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: .defaultSessionConfiguration())
let url = NSURL(string: my_url_string)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
   do {
       self.tableData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [NSDictionary]
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
          self.tableView.reloadData()
       })
   } catch let error {
        print(error)
   }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

My question is: should I wrap all of this code block into a background queue? Should I do as follows:

```
let download_queue = dispatch_queue_create("download", nil)
dispatch_async(download_queue) { () -> Void in
     previous code here
}
```

Or should I use one of the given high priority queues such as:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)
```

Also, when making additional network requests on subsequent view controllers, should I use the same queue I use here or should I create a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `NSURLSession` API is highly asynchronous. Usefull information from the Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsession?language=objc).

There is no visible issues that indicate to wrap you're code block with `GCD` and also completion block runs on background thread so there is right usage of the `GCD` to update `UITableview`

Comment: Thanks so much! So your saying I don't need to change my original code? It is good as is?

Comment: As far as I see there is no need to use additional GCD blocks. But at all it is ok.